# Passenger fails install with "RAKE APACHE2" giving libldap_r-2.4.so.2: "undefined reference to `sasl_..."

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, passenger

I installed Passenger 3.0.7 (also happens with 3.0.6) on Ubuntu on EC2.

I can't get it to install.  When I run: **RAKE APACHE2**

I get the error:
**/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_global_listmech@SASL2'**

Does anyone know why?  Or how to fix it?

```
creating libev.la
(cd .libs && rm -f libev.la && ln -s ../libev.la libev.la)
g++ ext/common/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp -o agents/PassengerLoggingAgent -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libe -I/bitnami/rubystackDev-linux/output/common/include -DHAS_CURL_EASY_RESET  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/loal/include -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_NAMESPACE="__gnu_cxx" -DHASH_FUN_H="<hash_fun.h>" -HAS_SFENCE -DHAS_LFENCE -Wall -g -DPASSENGER_DEBUG -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS ext/common/libpassengercommon.a ext/common/libboost_oxt.a ext/libev/.libs/libev.a -L/bitnami/rubystackDev-linux/output/comon/lib -lcurl -L/bitnami/rubystackDev-linux/output/common/lib -L/bitnami/rubystackDev-linux/outpu/common/lib -lz -lpthread -rdynamic
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_global_listmech@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_set_mutex@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_encode@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_client_start@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_client_init@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_errdetail@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_version@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_errstring@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_dispose@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_setprop@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_getprop@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_decode@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_client_step@SASL2'
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: undefined reference to `sasl_client_new@SASL2'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ ext/common/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp -o ag...]
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be good to log an issue on http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/list .  I'd suggest going back to ~3.0.2 and seeing if that works.

Comment: Thank.  I'll absolutely do that.  I posted here: http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/ but it hasn't gone past the moderator yet.